# C++ Builder 10.3 Rio - Existing and working projects started throwing exceptions on build

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

C++ Builder started throwing the following exception on all existing and working applications:

- From CPU window:  `50159CEE 83780800         cmp dword ptr [eax+$08],$00`
- From Event Log: `First chance exception at $50159CEE. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x50159cee: read of address 0x00000008'. Process blahblah.exe (9688)`

I'm guessing this is a compiler related issue, but I have no idea how to fix it. Tried to toggle "Use classic Borland compiler", didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by unchecking:

- Link with runtime packages,
- Link with dynamic RTL

(They were both `false`, but for some reason they went `true`)